# Getting my Android App to vibrate with a wasItTouched event

Tags: java, android, android-vibration

I have an app that has some objects (sprites) moving around the screen.  I would like the phone to vibrate when they are touched/clicked on but I'm having some trouble.

What I did was add what I thought would work in the wasItTouched method (in the sprite class) as seen below:

```
public boolean wasItTouched(float ex, float ey) {
    boolean touched = false;
    if ((x <= ex) && (ex < x + bmp_width) &&
            (y <= ey) && (ey < y + bmp_height)) {
        touched = true;

        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(500);
        //mySound.play(zapSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);


    }

    return touched;
}
```

As you can probably see from the 'comments' I have tried to add a sound but that didn't work either.

I wonder if I'm just not putting it in the right place.

I have declared it in the manifest (see below):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

When I go to click on the sprite (or anywhere on the screen for that matter), the app crashes.

Below is what I'm getting from logcat:

```
04-24 17:32:56.192 7551-7551/cct.mad.lab D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-24 17:32:56.192 7551-7551/cct.mad.lab W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d7cb20)
04-24 17:32:56.192 7551-7551/cct.mad.lab E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: cct.mad.lab, 
PID: 7551
                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                                                           at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4532)
                                                           at cct.mad.lab.Sprite.wasItTouched(Sprite.java:136)
                                                           at cct.mad.lab.GameView.onTouchEvent(GameView.java:187)
                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
                                                           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 17:32:56.192 1591-1711/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity cct.mad.lab/.GameActivity
```

If anyone can offer any guidance I would be most grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"

You're somehow calling this before onCreate is called on that activity, which isn't legal.  The main case that happens in is if you either call a function in the object's init as a default value, or if you try to create an Activity via new (which should never be done).

Comment: services not available to Activities before onCreate()
I believe wasItTouched(), is called from onClick and you might be registering the click event before the onCreate() method is executed.

Comment: I don't actually have an onClick. I have a MotionEvent in the following method in the GameView class: public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
   sprite = new Sprite(this);
   hitCount++;

   return true;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 }

Comment: @emulus Something there can't be right.  Here you have wasItTouched on the sprite, and wasItTouched is calling getSystemService which means it needs to be a Context-  probably an Activity.  If that's the case, your class hierarchy is completely wrong.  If that's not, the code you pasted isn't actually the code you're running.

Comment: @GabeSechan I thought getSystemService was the only option when it came to setting up the vibrate function

Comment: @emulus It is, but you would either call it from a function in the activity, or pass the class that wants to call it a Context to call it on.  You wouldn't make that class a Context.  Or if you are passing it a Context, the code you have up there isn't what you're using.

Comment: @GabeSechan I see.  I shall relook at the code and see where I've gone wrong. Thanks for the advice